# asking about data base

Tags: php, mysql

```
function main2(){
 $sql = mysql_query("select * from clubs,venue where id<>".$_SESSION['userid']);

  $cnt = 0;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)like
 <td width="19%"><?php echo $row['club_name'];?></td>
```

when I use this code, my entry will be double show to me. What wrong with this like club name will be show twice to me.

Comment: can you check the PHP above and replace it with something that is valid and complete, with regards to syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you don't JOIN the tables in your SQL query so the engine doesn't know how the data are related.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a JOIN on the clubs and venue table. Depending on how your rows are saved, it'll give you all the possible matches. If you have a specific result in mind, please explain it and we'll need your database schema (the structure of your DB) as well.